# Combinations of $6$-digit natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics

In each of the following 6-digit natural numbers: $333333,225522,118818,707099$,
every digit in the number appears at least twice. Find the number of such 6-digit natural numbers.

This is how I'm intending to do.

1) Find the total number of 6-digit combinations.

2) Subtract the number of times there's 0 and 1 repetition of digits so that I can get at least 2 repetitions.

Total Combinations = $9 \times 10^5$

Repeat 0 Times = $9 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5$

Repeat 1 Time = Not sure how to calculate

The answer is 11754  but I'm struggling to get it!

Comment: For 'repeat $0$ times, you seem to be counting cases with no repeated digits.  I'm thinking for 'repeat $1$ time' you are calculating cases with one repeated digit (e.g., 353217).  But there are other cases to consider such as two repeated digits and two singles; or a triple digit, a double digit, and a single; etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let us also accept numbers starting with a $0$.

Let $d$ denote the number of **distinct** digits in the number. For $d>3$ there are $0$ possibilities.

For $d=1$ there are $10$ choices of the digit and every choice leads to $1$ possibility.

For $d=3$ there are $\binom{10}{3}=120$
choices for the digits and each choice leads to $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}=90$
possibilities.

For $d=2$ we have two split-ups.

One of them is $6=3+3$
with $\binom{10}{2}=45$ choices for the digits and each choice leads
to $\binom{6}{3}=20$ possibilities.

The other is $6=4+2$. Here the
chosen digits are *distinghuisable*. One of them is used $4$ times
and the other $2$ times. So we have $10\times9=90$ choices and each
choice leads to $\binom{6}{2}=\binom{6}{4}=15$ possibilities.

Adding up we find $10\times 1+120\times90+45\times20+90\times15=13060$ possibilities.

> Subtracting the numbers that start with a $0$ we find $\frac{9}{10}\times13060=11754$
>   possibilities.

Comment: Thanks drhab! I'm slightly unclear why the numbers starting with a 0 is one tenth of the total.

Comment: Thought about it again and I got it! =)

Comment: For d=2, for the case where one digit is used 4 times and the other 2 times, why do we have $10 \times 9$ choices?

Comment: First choose the digit that appears $4$ times in the number. There are $10$ options. Then choose the digit that appears $2$ times. $9$ options are left. This gives $10\times 9$ possible choices.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand why don't we do the same for the case where $d=3$? The first digit can be chosen in 10 ways, the second 9 ways and the third 8 ways?

Comment: If e.g. the first choice is a $0$, the second a $1$ and the third a $2$, then you end up with the same result if e.g the first choice is a $1$, the second a $2$ and the third a $0$. This is doublecounting and must be avoided.

Comment: Can't this be said for the d = 2 also? If the first choice is 0 and the second choice is a 1, we get the same result e.g the first choice is a 1 and the second  a 0?

Comment: No, if $d=2$ and the split up is $6=4+2$ then if the first choice is a $0$ and the second a $1$ then you have $4$ times a $0$ and $2$ times a $1$. It the first choice is a $1$ and the second a $0$ then you have $2$ times a $0$ and $4$ times a  $1$. These situtations are distinct. That's why I used the term **distinguishable** in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying! Really appreciate it.

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: @drhab What if the repetition is global meaning not specific to a digit but whole number? How to get all the variations between 0 and 1000000 with for example 4 repetitions?

Comment: @Eftekhari I do not understand what you are trying to ask. Anyhow, if your question is okay then this spot is not the place to handle it. You could just *pose* your question eventually with a link to this answer.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for the reply. This is the question that I have >> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247472/permutations-with-global-limited-repetition-without-the-need-for-providing-digit

Comment: @drhab Very simple, how to get count of variations with n repetitions allowed; not more, not less.

Comment: @drhab Like all the variations between 0000000000 and 9999999999 with 5 repetition in each number.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd suggest direct counting, with cases being: (1) same digit six times; (2) a quadruple digit and a double digit; (3) two triple digits; (4) three double digits. Things get a bit messier because if one of your digits is $0$, you need to keep it out of the leading position.

Let's try counting case (3), and I'll leave the other cases to you:

Case 3a: Two triple digits, neither being $0$: Choose two nonzero digits ($9 \choose{2}$ ways).  Pick three of six positions for one of the digits ($6\choose 3$ ways). This gives a total of $36\cdot 20=720$ possibilities for this subcase.

Case 3b: Two triple digits, one being $0$: Choose a nonzero digit for the other digit (9 ways).  Choose $3$ of $5$ positions for the $0$s (you have to avoid the first position). This gives $9\cdot {5\choose 3}=90$ possibilities for this subcase.

So your total for case 3 is $720+90=810$.

Comment: Thanks, but I found the above answer easier to understand. =)